# Visual C++ : trying to convert binary to ascii value

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have problem with my binary to ASCII conversion what i have done is i have array of text boxes and i am trying to put binary values into that text boxes and passes those values to the function written as below :

```
System::String^ conversion(const char* input)
{
     int length = strlen(input);     //get length of string
 int binary[8];    //array used to store 1 byte of binary number (1 character)
 int asciiNum = 0;      //the ascii number after conversion from binary
 System::String^ ascii;      //the ascii character itself

     int z = 0;   //counter used

 for(int x = 0; x < length / 8; x++)     //reading in bytes. total characters 
 {
     for(int a = 0; a < 8; a++)      //store info into binary[0] through binary[7]
     {
     binary[a] = (int) input[z] - 48;      //z never resets
     z++;
     }

  int power[8];    //will set powers of 2 in an array
  int counter = 7;        //power starts at 2^0, ends at 2^7
  for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
  {
      power[x] = counter;      //power[] = {7, 6, 5, ..... 1, 0}
      counter--;    //decrement counter each time
  }

  for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++)    //will compute asciiNum
  {
      double a = binary[y];    //store the element from binary[] as "a"
      double b = power[y];    //store the lement from power[] as "b"

      asciiNum += a* pow(2, b);   
  }
  ascii = System::Convert::ToString(asciiNum);  

  asciiNum = 0;    //reset asciiNum for next loop
  return ascii;
}               
 }
```

the problem is i only get the ASCII value and couldn't get the related character. I want that character any one help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: `System::Convert` uses Unicode, not ASCII. Embrace it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to print an integer as a character. Instead of using ToString, you could recast the integers to characters:

```
(char)asciiNum
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int beta=100;
cout<<"Value of integer is: "<<beta<<endl;
cout <<"Value of char is: "<<(char) beta<<endl;

}
```

Results:

```
Value of integer is : 100

Value of char is : d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char asciichar=(unsigned char) asciinum;
```

This will convert your number to ascii character and you can return the result as `char` instead of `std::string`

Comment: thank you. I will try this one and then get back to you

Comment: I have tried it but it will still return ASCII value.

Comment: I m using visual c++ . is it possible that the problem come from visual c++ because whenever i checked the value of ASCII at runtime it will show like : '82'|R .

Comment: My input string is 01010010 and ascii value is during debugging 82|'R'.

Comment: what do you want for 01010010 value 82 or R